# Triggers in migration from Firebird to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, firebird, database-migration, firebird1.5

I need to migrate a database from Firebird 1.5 to PostgreSQL (version 8.4, that's the version installed in the server of my customer. It's not under my control so I can't update).

I used the trial version of the EasyFrom program, and it worked for the tables, but it seems that the triggers were not migrated (I used the `select * from pg_trigger` command and the triggers I wanted to migrate were not shown; also in pgAdmin, in Schemas > Public > Tables > specific_table > Trigger there's nothing)

Is there a program or a simple way to migrate the triggers? Or do I need to manually create the trigger migration?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why migrate to 9.1 _today_? 9.1 is end-of-life in 7 months. If you are doing the upgrade today (2016) you should go for 9.4 or 9.5

Comment: No specific reason, it's just the version I have in my computer, and I thought I should specify the version.

Actually is worse: the client server use PostgreSQL 8.4... I'll edit the question

Comment: Triggers often contain procedural code of some sort, which could make this rather complicated, as different DBMSes use different procedural languages.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, that's true... so probably it would be (very) hard for one automated tool to migrate the triggers. I guess that there's probably no way to evade from manual migration for triggers...

Comment: That was my thinking. It may be possible *for your particular triggers*, depending on what they look like - e.g. if you have a lot of similar, quite simple triggers, you could write a script to "translate" them using some quite specific templates - but the makers of a 3rd-party tool don't know to make those assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I understand, you're probably right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: every database has their own dialect for triggers, and their own quirks you need to take into account. Although it could be possible to translate this automatically, there are - as far as I am aware - no tools that do this for you.

In other words: you will need to do this yourself.